# RでCSVファイルを read.table で読み込む時にエラー: 入力コネクション 'Shugyoritu.csv' に不正な入力がありました

Tags: r, csv

以下の通り実行すると、エラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
> shugyoritu <- read.csv("Shugyoritu.csv", header=T, fileEncoding="utf-8")
 read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  でエラー: 
   入力中には利用可能な行がありません 
 追加情報:  警告メッセージ: 
 read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
   入力コネクション 'Shugyoritu.csv' に不正な入力がありました
```

なお、使用したデータは以下のページのダウンロードを押して入手しました。

https://dashboard.e-stat.go.jp/timeSeriesResult?indicatorCode=0301010000010020000

Comment: エラーメッセージ「入力中には利用可能な行がありません」から、`Shugyoritu.csv` の中身が空である可能性が高いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。今、メモ帳にコピペして確認したところ、区切り文字がカンマではなくインデントになっていたので、インデントをカンマに置換したら読み込めました。